# ¿Cómo quitar espacios en Bootstrap?

Tags: css, bootstrap, bootstrap-3

Estoy comenzando con algo de diseño web pero me he encontrado con este problema que llevo un buen rato intentando quitarlo. Me gustaría eliminar el espacio que está entre el logo de la página y el link de Inicio:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```
<body>
    <nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
        <div class="container">
            <ul class="nav navbar-header">
                <a href="index.jsp"><img src="images/LOGO.png" width="15%"/></a>
            </ul>
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                <li class="col-xl-3"><a href="index.jsp">Inicio</a></li>
                <li class="col-xl-3"><a href="login.jsp">Entrar</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </nav>
</body>
```

Uso las definiciones por defecto de Bootstrap 3, no he modificado nada.

Comment: no es `col-xs-3` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Las clases para columnas son `.col-xs-` para dispositivos muy pequeños , `.col-sm-` dispositivos pequeños , `.col-md-` dispositivos medianos y `.col-lg-` dispositivos grades.

Quizá la clase que desea hacer referencia es a `col-xs` en lugar de `col-xl` , además tener cuidado con ese `width` de `15%`  es lo que ocasiona que el primer enlace se separe tanto , además le hacen falta unos detalles para el modo `responsive` como el menú `collapse`  *(posible resultado final)*

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
  <div class="container">
      <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#nav" aria-expanded="false">
        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </button>
      <a href="index.jsp"><img src="images/LOGO.png" width="80"/></a>
    </div>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="nav">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
          <li ><a href="index.jsp">Inicio</a></li>
          <li ><a href="login.jsp">Entrar</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>
```

Comment: Muchas gracias Dev. Joel !! era principalmente el width el que me estaba dando el problema. Lo cambié como me dijiste y quedó perfect!

Comment: @Jonathan Qué bien , perfecto entonces. Saludos

Answer (score 1):

El problema está al ponerle a tu imagen `width="15%"`, según la [documentación](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/CSS/width):

> La propiedad CSS width especifica la anchura del area de contenido de un elemento. El área de contenido está dentro del padding, borde, y margen del elemento.

Y al ponerle un porcetaje tomará como referencía el ancho del contenedor, en conclusión le estás diciendo a tu imagen que ocupe el 15% de su contenedor

Quita ese pedazo del código y estarás bien.

Te dejo la documentación sobre los [atributos](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Attributes) que llevan las tags